# prove that if A is an elementary set, then $\mu^*(A_n) \leq \mu(A)$

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

How did they justify the last statement regarding how the sum of additive functions is less than the infimum plus $\epsilon$

Comment: While in English, the name of the Greek letter $\mu$ is pronounced like "mew", the TeX command is `\mu`. Similarily, $\nu$ is given by `\nu` and not `\new`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $S$ is lower bounded, non-empty set of real numbers then, by the definition of [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Properties) (or greatest lower bound), for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $s\in S$ such that
$$ s\leq \inf(S)+\epsilon.$$
In your case the non negative number $\mu^{\ast}(A)$ is defined as
$$\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n):\mbox{
$\{A_n\}_n$ is a sequence of open elementary sets such that $A\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$
}\right\},$$
Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$ there  is a sequence of open elementary sets $\{A_n\}_n$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)\leq \mu^{\ast}(A)+\epsilon.$$